# Preserving color output with cut

Tags: shell, command-line, ls, pipe, colors

Using bash interactively I am trying to use cut to prevent the lines from going longer than my terminal width.  But when using a command with colorized output all the color gets removed by cut.  For example:  `ls -lG | cut -c 1-$COLUMNS`.

Is there anyway to get cut to preserve the color formatting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got two problems here

1. `ls -G` stops outputting in colour when the output doesn't go to a terminal (here to a pipe instead). GNU `ls` needs to be passed a `--color=always` option, and for BSD `ls`, you need to set the environment `CLICOLOR_FORCE` to a non-empty value to tell it to always output in colour.
2. Colours are achieved by outputting escape sequences that are a sequence of characters like `<ESC>[1;31m` for foreground bold red. That doesn't have any width when displayed, but as far as `cut` is concerned, that's 7 bytes or characters which will count up to `$COLUMNS`.

   So you can't use `cut` here as you need to ignore those escape sequences in the calculation. Instead, you could do something like:

   ```
   esc=$'\e' # or esc=$(printf '\33') if your shell doesn't do $'...'
   CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -l | sed "
     s/^\(\(\($esc\[[0-9;]*m\)*.\{0,1\}\)\{$COLUMNS\}\).*/\1${esc}[m/"
   ```

   There, `sed` does the counting and adds a `\e[m` to revert the colour to default in case it has been cut in the process.

   Note that while it handles multi-byte single-width characters (contrary to the GNU implementation of `cut` whose current versions treat `-c` the same as `-b`), it doesn't handle zero-width or double-width characters nor tabulations or other control characters.

Alternatively, you could tell your terminal not to wrap and do the cutting itself with:

```
tput rmam
```

(for reset mode auto-margin; `tput smam` to restore)

You could define a function like:

```
nowrap() {
  [ -t 1 ] && tput rmam
  "$@"; local ret="$?"
  [ -t 1 ] && tput smam
  return "$ret"
}
alias nowrap='nowrap '
```

(the `alias` part to force alias expansion after `nowrap`), to be called as:

```
nowrap ls -l ...
```

Comment: `tput rmam` is an interesting idea; alas, it keeps overwriting the last column with the received character, that is, the last column will contain the last character of the input line, which is unexpected behavior. (Also, who knows what happens if double wide characters or combining accents are encountered at that position.)

Comment: Doesn't work in `bash` due `$COLUMNS` not being available in a script.  See [workarounds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317344/143394).

Answer (score 2):

`man ls`:

```
   --color[=WHEN]
          colorize  the  output;  WHEN  can be 'never', 'auto', or 'always' (the
          default); more info below
```

Your `ls` is probably configured for `--color=auto`, which means it only outputs color if it is directly connected to a terminal. (And not to another command like cut.)

You can use `--color=always` but be aware that the whole color stuff works by inserting special characters (escape sequences) which turn color on and off. If you cut in the middle of a colored word you will remove the "stop coloring" sequence and the next line will be colored, too.

Maybe `ls --color=always|less -RS` will do what you want.

Comment: That would be the right answer on Linux, but the BSD version of `ls` doesn't have an exact equivalent of `--color=always`.

Answer (score 1):

To fake output to a terminal and thus preserve the color formatting `ls` can be run in a pseudo-terminal using the (FreeBSD) `script` command (or tools such as [ptymagic.c](http://jineshkj.wordpress.com/2006/12/26/using-ptys-to-fool-getpass/)).

```
script -q /dev/null ls -lG | tr -d '\r' | cut -c 1-$COLUMNS

ptymagic ls -lG | cut -c 1-$COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 0):

`less -RS` is the closest easy solution that I can think of. The well-known pager `less` can be asked to handle color-changing escape sequences (`-R`) and to chop long lines (`-S`).

It also has options like `-E` to quit at end of file, and `-F` to quit immediately if the contents fit on the screen.

It would be interesting to see if `less`'s developer would be open to a feature request for your desired behavior. It doesn't really fit the purpose of `less`, but this is the utility that already has basically all the required blocks implemented, and would be the easiest to extend to support your feature request.

Comment: Note that `less` does more transformation, like transforming unprintable characters in some `^X` or `<XX>` or  `<U+XXXX>` notation (which may (likely) or may not be desirable).

Comment: Good point, thanks for pointing this out! Unless your utility knows what these unprintable characters (or complete escape sequences containing them) do and handles them appropriately, it's impossible to count the columns. So you either need to filter them out / replace them (probably my preferred approach, too), or risk the output not being formatted as desired if the input contains such characters (probably also good enough for OP's purpose). ... Alas I can't see a great quick solution for OP's exact problem, one would need to write a nontrivial utility from scratch for that specific purpose.

Comment: less -RSEX seems to do exactly what OP is asking for, with the bonus of paging if there is more than a screen's worth