# Truncate output to terminal width (colour and wide char aware)

Tags: terminal, colors, escape-characters, cut

I have the alias:

```
trunc='cut -c -${COLUMNS:-80}'
```

This works just dandy when text doesn't contain colours and wide characters.

I could play with `tput rmam` and `tput smam`, but these don't actually shorten the output, which may contain insanely long binary lines if the input is something like `rg`.

Is there a way to truncate the displayed line and remove all non-displayed characters from the output?

Comment: Do you want to preserve colors? Would piping through `tr -dc '[[:print:]]'` be sufficient for your purpose?

Comment: @FelixJN I truly doubt this command would do anything useful, since color changing escape sequences are a mixture of non-printable and printable characters (in fact, only the first character (the escape) is non-printable, the rest are printable).

Comment: Tom, I'm truly wondering: What is your use case? By the way, the closest I can think of is `less -RS`, that is, the well-known pager in a mode where it interprets color-changing sequences and chops long lines. Alternatively, you'd have to code it up manually: recognizing some of the most frequent escape sequences, at the very least `ESC ... m` aka SGR, and also do the width computation using `isprint()` and `wcwidth()` (or friends) on the remaining characters.

Comment: @egmont `rg -uuu --color always` is an example use case.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas thanks, [your answer with `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109215/143394) provided the solution.